# Java LocalDate parser does not take hours, minutes, seconds into account

Tags: java, localdate

I want to parse DateTime from a string.
Here is my code:

```
String dateStr = "2016-08-18T14:44:56.225Z"
final String Pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Pattern);
LocalDate dt = dtf.parseLocalDate(dateStr);
```

Then I only receive Year, Month and Day (2016-08-18) from the code above.
I cannot get Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

Did anyone get this problem before? How did you solve that?
I use Java 7.

Comment: Well, that's what a date is. Use LocalDateTime to get time, too.

Comment: Looks like I have just asked a silly question :). Anyway, thanks a lot for your help @mszymborski.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LocalDateTime` to get time, too:

```
String dateStr = "2016-08-18T14:44:56.225Z"
final String Pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Pattern);
LocalDateTime dt = dtf.parseLocalDateTime(dateStr);
```

You are also ignoring the time zone (UTC/Zulu in this case - the `Z` at the end) - make sure if you really want to do this.